# How to handle undefined response from AJAX call on Autocomplete box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, xml

I have the following function:

```
function GetGames(request) {
    //Replace spaces with a '+'
    var url = request.term.replace(/\s/g,"+");
    return $.ajax({
        'url': "php/gamescript.php?search=" + url, 
        'dataType': 'json'
    }).then(function(data){
        return $.map(data.Game || [], function(v,i){
            return {
                label: v.GameTitle + ' Game (' + v.ReleaseDate + ')',
                value: v.GameTitle 
            }
        });
    })
}
```

and above it, code that handles the returned data:

```
function AutoComplete() {
    $(".searchbox").autocomplete({  
        source: function(request, response) {  
            $.when( GetGames(request) )
            .done(function(games) {

                var term = request.term.toLowerCase();
                var combine = games
                    .map((v,i) => {
                        //precompute such values if possible
                        return {
                            titleLowerCase: v.value.toLowerCase(),
                            termOffset: (v.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(term)+1) || Infinity,
                            //and keep a reference to the original data
                            data: v
                        }
                    })
                    .sort((a, b)=>{
                        //sortOn(termOffset ASC, titleLowerCase ASC)
                        return (a.termOffset - b.termOffset) || 
                        (a.titleLowerCase !== b.titleLowerCase && a.titleLowerCase > b.titleLowerCase? 1: -1) || 0;
                    })
                    .map(v => v.data).slice(0, 15);

                response(combine);   
            });
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is that sometimes, the search on gamescript.php will return 'undefined', which will then cause this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

What is a good way to handle this error? I tried doing a simple approach:

```
 return {
     label: v.GameTitle + ' Game (' + v.ReleaseDate + ')',
     value: v.GameTitle || " "
 }
```

which at least makes the code *run*, but it ends up creating Autocomplete suggestions that say 'undefined' as the label. I also tried to write an if statement in the GetGames function, but ultimately I struggle with introducing new code without creating new errors with it.

In case it's needed, the gamescript.php code is:

```
<?php 
    $xml_string = file_get_contents("http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=".$_REQUEST['search']);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    echo $json;
?>
```

Edit: I've now tried this code:

```
function GetGames(request) {
    //Replace spaces with a '+'
    var url = request.term.replace(/\s/g,"+");
    return $.ajax({
        'url': "php/phpscript.php?search=" + url, 
        'dataType': 'json'
    }).then(function(data){
        return $.map(data.Game || [], function(v,i){
            if( typeof( v.GameTitle )!='undefined' ){
                return {
                    label: v.GameTitle + ' Game (' + v.ReleaseDate + ')',
                    value: v.GameTitle 
                }
            }
        });
    })
}
```

edit: I've since realized that if I add `alert(data.Game.GameTitle);` in the GetGames function, it successfully alerts the title of the game despite showing up as 'undefined' in the Autocomplete list. I have no idea why this is happening... Again, this error occurs when I search 'Hunger'. For other game queries I've tried, it works fine.

Comment: in javascript you can do something like `if( typeof( var )=='undefined' ){/**/}` or `if( typeof( var )!='undefined' ){/**/}`